# SUSER_SID support for Azure SQL

Tags: sql-server, azure, ssms

SUSER_SID has two optional parameters. I am using only first 'login'. Documentation for it applies to Azure SQL Database, but it doesn't work. For 'login' parameter is says *"Applies to: SQL Server 2008 and later"*.

When I call `SELECT SUSER_SID('test');`
using SSMS, I get the error:

> 'SUSER_SID' cannot be invoked with parameters in this version of SQL Server.

I am using Azure SQL Server ver. 12.0.2000.8

How is that possible, what am I missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Odd, this isn't actually [documented](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/suser-sid-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) but I get the same problem. (Will raise this on the document's GitHub).

If you want the `sid` you could use `sys.database_principals` instead:

```
SELECT dp.sid
FROM sys.database_principals dp
WHERE dp.name = N'test';
```

Answer (score 0):

for this question I asked Azure Support. They told me that:

> Based on the online document, the parameter “login” applies to SQL Server 2008 and later version, and the parameter2 applies to SQL Server 2012 and later version. That is the reason why we will get the error message “'SUSER_SID' cannot be invoked with parameters in this version of SQL Server.” while running the command SELECT SUSER_SID('serveradmin') , because Azure SQL database does not support SUSER_SID() with parameters.

If you want to check the SID, please consider running the command in below instead:

```
select name, sid from sys.sql_logins where name = 'test'
```

Here's the screenshots:

[image]

Hope this helps.